# How can I connect standard output and error of a systemd service to a file with a date in the path?

Tags: logging, systemd, stdout, systemd-service, stderr

I would like to run a server process under systemd, and append its standard output and error to a file, where the file path has a date in it, like this:

/initech/logs/tps-report-app/sales/2023/09/11/console.log

Ideally, I would like that path to roll automatically when the date changes, but it's not the end of the world if it doesn't, since we restart our servers overnight anyway.

One thing i don't want to do is do traditional log rotation, where output is written to a file with a fixed path, and then rotated to a file with a dated path later.

The [StandardOutput configuration option](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=) lets me append output to a file using `append:path`, but there's no mention of variable substitution in that string, so i assume it has to be fixed. Is there some way to incorporate the date into this path?

If not, what is the best approach here? Connect the output via a named pipe or some such to a log daemon like multilog? Is there anything in the systemd 'toolkit' like that? Wrap the server process with a chain loader kind of script which redirects standard output and error? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, roll the logs daily with `logrotate`. Instead of using `StandardOutput` you could tell your software to send logs to /path/$( something-bashy here)/console.log and as part of `postrotate` create the path, then restart the service in question.

Edit: just noticed you mention servers are restarted nightly. Then your only concern is making sure the logfile path exist. In this case I'd incorporate the creation of the logfile path into `ExecStart`. Something like

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -ac \
  "mkdir /my/path -p && run_app.sh"
```

Comment: The app writes to standard output, and i can't change that - and i have many such apps. I could wrap each one in a shell script which redirects the output. What i'm asking is whether there is a way to do this in systemd config.